# Counting numbers of sets in a list

Tags: python, set

I have a list of sets constructed as below. I want to count how many times the set s1 appears in the list. My approach right now is converting each set to tuple and count them. Is there another solution for this?

```
s1 = {1, 2}
s2 = {1, 3, 4}
s3 = {1, 4}

s = [s1, s2, s1, s3]

# This won't work because set is unhashable
# c = Counter(s)

s = [tuple(i) for i in s]
c = Counter(s)
print(c)
```

Comment: Why would you need another solution? This looks like a good approach for me.

Comment: In fact you can also use the hashable `frozenset`.

Comment: @ex4, I'll need to convert the tuple back to set again for further uses. I just thought that there might be a solution that I don't need to covert back and forth

Comment: Can't you just do `the_list.count(some_set)` ?

Comment: @AMC, I would need to know the set beforehand to do that. Basically, I am trying to find the set that appears the most in the list

Comment: @NepNep what about using dict?

Comment: @shivank98, `frozenset` like Austin suggested would be better than dict. However, I am too deep into my code to change the structure right now

Comment: @NepNep right, I somehow missed that.

Comment: If you need your list of sets, why you don't just convert it to list on tuples on-place. like `Counter([tuple(i) for i in s])`

Comment: @NepNep _I would need to know the set beforehand to do that. Basically, I am trying to find the set that appears the most in the list_ Then please edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: Unfortunately relevant: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16093